# Error adding Nativescript to Angular 8 project with SCSS

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to add Nativescript to an existing Angular 8.2.11 project built with SCSS. Adding the @nativescript/schematics is giving an error.

It is not giving an error when installing in a CSS based project.

I'm trying to add Nativescript to an existing Angular 8.2.11 project. I am getting an error. I can reproduce it on a new project with the following steps:

---

```
> ng new ang-ns
Angular routing: y
Stylesheets: scss

> ng serve [serves web correctly]

> ng add @nativescript/schematics
...
...
Failed to find generated component file /auto-generated.component.css. Please contact the @nativescript/schematics author.

> ng add @nativescript/schematics --style=scss
...
...
Failed to find generated component file /auto-generated.component.css. Please contact the @nativescript/schematics author.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out this issue on their repo - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/238, looks like they just fixed it, try `ng add @nativescript/schematics@next`

Comment: Yes, it is now working. Thanks.